# How to get average YTD

Tags: sql-server

The table is as follows.

```
Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
25  20  45  10  15  23  23  17  19  21  24  33
```

I want to display average upto previous month. Means, if this is August, I want to display till July. If the current month is September, I want to get till July. The table should be as follows.

```
Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec Avg
25  20  45  10  15  23  23  17  19  21  24  33  23
```

Comment: You've only showed us data for Jan through Dec in the above table.  What if I wanted to show August through July?  Is your table a derived table?

Comment: Change your table design... that layout is red flag #1 for non-normalized tables.  Add a column for the year/month and another for the value.

Answer (score 2):

Your data format is very poor.  You would be better served with the data in columns.  But, you can do a painful query like this:

```
select ((case when month(getdate()) > 1 then jan else 0 end) +
        (case when month(getdate()) > 2 then feb else 0 end) +
        . . .
        (case when month(getdate()) > 11 then nov else 0 end)
       ) /
       ((case when month(getdate()) > 1 then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when month(getdate()) > 2 then 1 else 0 end) +
        . . .
        (case when month(getdate()) > 11 then 1 else 0 end)
       )
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Please help me with the following.                                 I have written code for pivot table in sql. In that, I have to add a YTD column which should display sum of data till previous month.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this?:

```
SELECT * INTO tbl_Month_AVG
FROM (VALUES
(25,1),(20,2),(45,3),(10,4),(15,5),(23,6),(23,7),(17,8),(19,9),(21,10),(24,11),(33,12)) as a(Num,Mon)

;WITH Avg_On as (
SELECT Mon, SUM(Num) OVER(ORDER BY Mon)
    / COUNT(*) OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as Avg_On
FROM tbl_Month_AVG
WHERE Mon < 8
)
SELECT Avg_On FROM Avg_On
WHERE Mon = (Select MAX(Mon) FROM Avg_On)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Please help me with the following.                                 I have written code for pivot table in sql. In that, I have to add a YTD column which should display sum of data till previous month.